# Why can ogr2ogr upload data to a not previously existing table faster than to an existing empty one?

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, bash

Recently I observed that it takes much less time for [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) to upload data to a PostGIS database if I do not create the destination table first.

I would like to understand why this happens. Below is a reproducible example.

---

**Create mock GeoJSON**

To create a GeoJSON with a million features, with columns `geometry` and `col0`, I do:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry

count = 1000000

gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_dict(
    dict(
        geometry=[
            shapely.geometry.Polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]])
            for _ in range(count)
        ],
        col0=["example_string" for _ in range(count)],
    )
).set_crs(4326).to_file("localdata.geojson", engine="pyogrio", layer="main")
```

I use this GeoJSON as source for a local database (see below).

---

**Prepare DB, do *not* prepare table, ingest**

I use this bash script to create a local PostGIS database named `source`:

```
dropdb --if-exists source --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres
createdb source --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres

psql --username postgres --dbname source --command "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

Notice that I do not create a table, only the database. Then, I load the GeoJSON data to the database, to a table named `localdata`:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" \
    PG:"port=5432 host=postgres host=localhost dbname=source" \
    localdata.geojson \
    -nln localdata
```

This `ogr2ogr` command took **12.20 seconds**. Alternatively, I could create the table in advance:

---

**Prepare DB, prepare table, check for lack of indexes, ingest**

As previously, let's create a database named `source`, but now let's also create table `localdata` before using `ogr2ogr`:

```
dropdb --if-exists source --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres
createdb source --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres

psql --username postgres --dbname source --command "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
psql --username postgres \
     --dbname source \
     --command "CREATE TABLE localdata ( col0 TEXT, wkb_geometry GEOMETRY);"
```

I do not create any indexes. To be sure there aren't any, I run:

```
psql --username postgres \
     --dbname source \
     --command "select count(*) from pg_indexes where tablename like '%localdata%'"
```

Output:

```
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

Reassuring. Then, I load GeoJSON data to database, same command as previously:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" \
    PG:"port=5432 host=postgres host=localhost dbname=source" \
    localdata.geojson \
    -nln localdata
```

This command took **42.71 seconds**.

---

I tried a few times, with differently sized GeoJSONs, and this pattern is always there: `ogr2ogr` is slower if the table already exists.

In my real-world scenario, I have an empty table (without indexes, just like the one above), to which I would like to ingest some data. Understanding the above described runtimes might help me speed up this process.

**Why is uploading to a table already created slower than uploading to a not previously created table?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the difference comes from this documented feature
https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html#configuration-options

> PG_USE_COPY=value: This may be "YES" for using COPY for inserting data to Postgresql. COPY is significantly faster than INSERT. COPY is used by default when inserting from a table that has just been created.

If you have an existing table then COPY is not used by default.

Notice that GDAL creates a spatial index into a new table by default https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html#layer-creation-options. You should take also that into account when running benchmarks.

Comment: You are right, adding `--config PG_USE_COPY YES` resulted in runtimes within 20% of each other.